# UICollectionView referenceSizeForHeaderInSection animation

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

Is it possible to animate the frame change of a UICollectionView header (also known as `UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader`) size change?

In other words, I would like my UICollectionView header to have two different possible frames, an expanded (larger height) and collapsed mode (smaller height). By tapping a button somewhere, I would like the header to switch between the expanded and collapsed mode with a custom animation.

Current I have it set to this:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: 0, height: HEADER_HEIGHT)
}
```

where I am changing the collection view height by calling this function upon a button tap

```
HEADER_HEIGHT = HEADER_HEIGHT == 100 ? 200 : 100
self.collectionView?.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
```

This works but I have yet to find documentation about animating the frame change. Is this even possible?

Comment: It seems that your question is similar to [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32933476/animate-uicollectionview-header-height-change), but unfortunately, no one answered it.

Answer (score 2):

You can animate any animatable view changes by calling them in the UIView's animation block:

```
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
        self.collectionView?.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
    }
```

Comment: This appears to be able to animate the `contentView` of the header, but it does not seem to animate the resizing of the header view?